# Приведите пример кода, как преобразовать строку вида name@domain.ru в строку domain.ru\name с помощью регулярных выражений python?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Дано:

```
 name@domain.ru
```

Надо:

```
domain.ru\name
```

с помощью регулярных выражений python.
Я знаю, как сделать это обычными методами, но вот нужно компактно с помощью регулярок.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rUvyXo/2, `r"([^@]+)@(.*)"`  что нибудь вроде этого, заменить на `\2/\1`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
s = "name@domain.ru"
result = re.sub(r'^([^@]+)@(.*)', r'\2/\1', s)
print(result)
```

Что обозначает следующее:

- Найти всё что от начала строки - первый `^`
- Не является знаком @ `[^@]` и выбирать от 1 до N знаков `+`
- пропустить знак @
- и в всё что за ним `(.*)`
- Вывести в позиции `\2` потом `\1` разделив знаком `/`

Comment: Осталось объяснить, что такое `\2` и `\1`

Comment: Ты круглыми скобочками выбираешь из текста "abcdefg" выборкой "a(bcd)e(fg)"     Так вот bcd это будет \1 , а вот fg будет \2

Comment: @EugeneX CrazyElf прекрасно знает, что такое \1 и \2. Он вам как-бы намекает, что неплохо пояснить это в самом ответе.